# I want to show warning message in jsf when downloading excel which is having records more than 10000 as well as user has able to download

Tags: jsf

I want to show warning message in jsf downloading excel file.

I want to show warning message in jsf when downloading excel which is having records more than 10000 as well as user has able to download

Comment: Throw an exception while preparing excel file having more than 10000 rows and stop the download.

Comment: You've managed to state what you want to do three times.  Have you managed to try to do it once?  How did that attempt go?  Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Thank you for reply the request is going new  in the faces context so the message added is not coming on jsp and that was my requirement i should not stop downlaoding...

Comment: Are you using JSF 1.2 or JSF 2?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to send multiple responses to one request. You can send only one response  back per request. So, in order to be able to send a warning message and a file for download, the client basically needs to send 2 requests.

Easiest would be if the first requests checks the size of the file and then sets the message accordingly.

```
public void submit() {
    excelFile = prepareExcelFile();

    if (excelFile.getRecordCount() > 10000) {
        addGlobalWarn("It's more than 1000 records! It can take quite some time.");
    }
}
```

And have the form submit conditionally render a JS `window.location` call on the exact URL of the excel file.

```
<h:outputScript rendered="#{not empty bean.excelFile}">
    window.location = '#{excelFile.url}';
</h:outputScript>
```